# "Your wife" or "your own wife"?

Tags: differences, phrase-meaning

What is the difference, if any, between "your wife" and "your own wife"? The latter is used in the Bible. Does it convey any more information than "your wife"?

Comment: I'm no expert on Biblical Greek, Hebrew, or Biblical translation, but to me (in modern usage), "your own wife" seems to emphasize the distinction between that person's wife and other people's wives. If Bob was hanging out with my wife, I might say, "Hey Bob, go hang out with your own wife."

Comment: There's nothing especially "biblical" about the usage.  It's simply a form of emphasis.

Comment: Actually, depends on the translation. In the KJV (assuming I haven't screwed up my search) I could find only 2 instances of "own wife" (in both cases "his own wife", rather than thy) and no instances of "own wives" so it may be an artefact of the translation as much as anything

Answer (score 7):

"Your *own* wife" is an expression which adds emphasis to the word *your*.

Since the Bible is filled with exhortations for a husband to love his wife, to be faithful to his wife, and to "cleave to" his wife (see Genesis 2:24 KJV), combining the word *own* with the word *your* emphasizes the importance of fidelity to one's *own* wife.

To *own*, of course, does not mean to possess, as you would a chattel; rather, it denotes a term of endearment, preciousness, exclusiveness, and even pride. Take the following sentence, for example:

> Helen is my own wife, not someone else's, and I'll love her until the day I die.

Comment: It's not "filled" with exhortations for a husband to love their wife, its known as a pretty fundamental pillar of a husband's role in marriage in Christianity. The most referred to passage is probably: Ephesians 5:25.

Comment: @kirgy: Can't agree with you on the Bible not being filled with exhortations regarding husbands loving their lives. If you don't like the word "exhortations," then how about the words "hortatory content" or "teaching"? I can, however, agree with you on the importance--if not centrality--of Paul's exhortation to the Christians in Ephesus, "Husbands, love your wives," as well as Paul's "So husbands ought also to love their own wives" in Ephesians 5:28, which follows on the heels of 5:25.  As for other passages with exhortations in this regard, see Proverbs, for one example.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the difference, if any, between "your wife" and "your own
>   wife"?

You use "your own" when you want to distinguish it from someone else's - esp. your own, for example:

```
Get your own fries and stop eating mine.
```

or:

```
Mind your own business.
```

which actually means don't meddle in mine.

> The latter is used in the bible.

First, there is no such thing as **the** bible (in English). There are more than 450 translations of the bible into English <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_into_English)</sup>.

Next, the phrase "your own wife" seems to appear only in [The Good News Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_News_Bible) version of Proverbs 5:15:

> Be faithful to your own wife and give your love to her alone.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+5%3A15&version=GNT

Now, the thing is that this is not a translation at all. The same verse in  the King James Version reads:

> Drink waters out of thine own cistern, and running waters out of thine
>   own well.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+5%3A15&version=KJV

which is close to the original Hebrew.

So clearly the expression "Be faithful to your own wife" quoted above is a paraphrase of the original verse. And it is concerned not with *fidelity* (be faithful to your wife) but rather with ***adultery*** (do not drink water out of the cisterns of others).

Replace the euphemism "be faithful" with another word conveying the original meaning, and you will see why it's necessary to say "your own wife" rather than just "your wife".

---

**P.S:** Further search reveals two additional occurrences of "your own wife", both in the [Holman Christian Standard Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holman_Christian_Standard_Bible) translation:

> 9 Why then have you despised the command of the Lord by doing what I
>   consider evil? You struck down Uriah the Hittite with the sword and
>   took his wife as your own wife—you murdered him with the Ammonite’s
>   sword. 10 Now therefore, the sword will never leave your house because
>   you despised Me and took the wife of Uriah the Hittite to be your own
>   wife.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel+12&version=HCSB

I don't think these require any explanation regarding the use of "own".

Answer (score 2):

A quick perusal of the entry in the Oxford English Dictionary, will illustrate that the word ***wife*** (Cognate with Old Frisian *wif*) has had many senses and meanings down the ages - most of them related to a mature and sexually-experienced woman (as opposed to a *maid*, or a *virgin*).

**The modern Western sense of the female member of a married partnership has not always been its interpreted meaning. Indeed OED's Section 1 of the meanings of *wife* is headed: "A woman considered without reference to marital status, and related senses".**

I am not clear which translation of the Bible you are quoting, but if it is the Authorised (KJV) it will be based on an early-seventeenth-century notion of *wife*. If you look at the following extracts from the OED around that time you will see that the term *wife* really means little more than the word *woman* would mean today.

> 1570   R. Sempill Regentis Trag. (single sheet)    The wyfis that
>   fostred ȝow.
>
> a1628   J. Carmichaell Coll. Prov. in Scots (1957) 96   Quhair there
>   is wyves, there are there words.
>
> 1721   A. Ramsay Poems I. 100   The Wives came furth, and up they rest
>   him, And fand Life in the Lown.
>
> 1794   Har'st Rig lviii. 21   The Embrugh wives them a' exceed For sad
>   mislear'd ill words indeed!

**All this suggests to me a possible explanation as to why the Bible might stress *your own wife*, for clarity's sake - i.e as distinct from a *wife* (for which read *woman*) you might happen to know.**

Comment: Those three references (*Carmichael, Ramsay, Har'st*) are all Scottish. Were you looking in the OSD? More seriously, I think it's likely that this sense was much more prevalent in Scotland than in England in the 17th and 18th centuries.

Comment: @PeterShor That's very interesting. Indeed the same OED sense contains two very recent examples, but which again are Scottish: *2004   S. Blackhall Wizard o the North 3   A hurricane's blootered Dunoon! Ilkie reeftap blew aff o the toon! They flew past Big Ben at a quarter tae ten, Wi a wife in an auld flannel goon! 2015   C. MacDonald in Lallans 87 74   The skrankie wee wife wi the dry hair an lang drab coat.* But how about Shakespeare's *Merry Wives of Windsor*. I'm not sure, but in what sense were they *wives*? Shakespeare was contemporaneous with the KJV, after all.

Comment: @PeterShor A couple of examples from the period which are definitely NOT Scottish: *1625   Bacon Apophthegmes §54. 73   Strawberrie wiues, that laid two or three great strawberries at the mouth of their pot, and all the rest were little ones.1631   Act of Common Council City of London 20 July in Jrnls. (Corporation of London) (London Metropolitan Archives: COL/CC/01) XXXV. f. 332,   Oyster wives, earbe wives Tripe wives.*

Answer (score 0):

I've studied Koine Greek at a Bible seminary.

The following example taken from Ephesians 5:25 shows a literal translation:

> "The husbands! love your own wives, as also the Christ did love the
>   assembly, and did give himself for it," (Ephesians 5:25, Young's Literal Translation)

The following example of the same passage shows a less literal, more message-felt translation:

> "Husbands, love your wives, just as Christ loved the church and gave
>   himself up for her" (Ephesians 5:25, NIV 2016)

For the Greek side of things, it seems largely to be a language translation choice.

In Greek, the start of this passage "Husbands, love your wives" is:

> οι ανδρες αγαπατε τας γυναικας

A transliteration of this could be:

> The husbands love the wives of yours

The important thing to notice here is the word used in Greek for "your wife" - γυναικας, meaning "wife of yours" - the genitive form of wife.

I'm suspecting the translators of more literal word-for-word translations such as NKJV or NIV as opposed to The Message or ESV used the word "own" also due to the word "τας" being the Greek female form of "the"; a word we would often omit in English as "husbands love your the wife" does not make sense. Instead, perhaps the translators used "husbands love your own wife" to be as literal as possible which being grammatically accurate in English.

Comment: Where is the word "own" in your example?

Comment: Its a word that does not come out in this particular engish translation, I suspect it is because the word "own" if placed in the translation would convey the wrong message; the Greek is a command to love your wife because love is the duty. If the word "own" were added it would convey that loving your /own/ wife were the duty. A nuance, but a change in meaning. So, no, there is no "own" in the English, but it is there in the Greek; a suffix ending to the word "wife" which is how genitive/possesive words are formed in Koine Greek.

Comment: "*So, no, there is no "own" in the English, but it is there in the Greek;*" How does your answer relate to the question, then?

Comment: I was demonstrating that the language in the Greek shows that the message "your own wife" is a valid translation whilst also explaining that the reason why this is used should not convey a different meaning in the translation. You could also read the NIV translation as "Husbands, love your own wives..." and this would be completely valid.

Comment: For a case in point, the "Darby Bible Translation" of this passage begins: "Husbands, love your own wives...". "Young's Literal Translation" also used similar language choice: "The husbands! love your own wives..."

Comment: I have added a further translation for clarity.